# How to use SQLCommand to update a row in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm creating a software to manage files. But when i try to update tags
that are added to the documents (in the database) it shows that is successful
but when i check, it is not done. Here is the code:

```
        borrarQuery = @"UPDATE dbo.correspondencia_FFAA " +
                        " SET tags_asignadas='NUEVO' " +
                        "@registro ,  @mensaje; ";
        stato = new SqlConnection(@"Server=BDSERVER\MIFFAASQL; Database=Miffaa; Trusted_Connection=True");
        updater = new SqlCommand(borrarQuery, stato);

private void btnBorrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updater = new SqlCommand();
        try
        {
            updater.Parameters.Add("@registro", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = txtno_reg.Text;
            updater.Parameters.Add("@mensaje", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = rtxMensaje.Text.ToString();
            updater.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = txtUser.Text;

            updater.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {            }
        finally 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Mensaje de Registro: " + txtno_reg.Text + " ha sido eliminado correctamente.");
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: where is your command text ??

Comment: Where's your update statement? You have to write an actual SQL query.

Comment: "it shows that is successful" you're just swallowing the exception, maybe? Not good.

Comment: no wonder that is "successful", since you are swallowing all exceptions, don't do that, it's evil

Comment: OK, new code. Now your problem is that you're overwriting `updater` when clicking the button, in the first line: `updater = new SqlCommand();`

Comment: You want to debug? Don't try to catch them first... Debug compile and see what's thrown at you. Then you know the reality...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you command statement is

```
"select * from dbo.correspondencia_FFAA " +
            "where usuario='DGTI.LOPEZ' and tags_asignadas='NUEVO'"
```

which select statement you need to use `Update` Query statement for updation

**Example :**

```
mySQLCommand.ComandText = "Update myTable set firstname=@firstname,
            lastname=@lastname where id=@id";
mySQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@firstname", "bob");
mySQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@lastname", "smith");
mySQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", "id3");
```